# Binary file cannot be transferred whereas text file can be

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, file-transfer

I need to transder a file from one application to another application on the same machine. I wrote code which transfers a packet structure which has fields like:

- **seq no**
- **round**
- **data**, which is an `unsigned char` indicating the data to be transferred
- **length**, which indicates how many bytes have been read using the `read` function
- **crc**, which is default string as of now

and a parameter, last, indicating that it is the last packet so that the file and connection can be closed.

This code works perfectly for ASCII files, but, when I use it to transfer a binary file, the diff of two files don't match. I am not able to figure out what the problem is. Can some one help me?

Here is the code for my sender. It connects to receiver on port 4950.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#define DATA 170
#define SERVERPORT "4950"       // the port users will be connecting to

typedef struct packet_ {
    unsigned short int seq;
    unsigned short int round;
    unsigned short int last;
    unsigned short int length;
    unsigned char  data[DATA];
    unsigned char crc[17];
} packet;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd;
    struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
    int rv;
    int numbytes;
    int max_seq_no = 10;
    packet send;
    FILE *fp;
    unsigned short int seq =0, round =0;
    long int totalBytes = 0;
    unsigned short int bytes_read =0;

    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr,"usage: talker hostname message\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE; // use my IP
    if ((rv = getaddrinfo(NULL, SERVERPORT, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
        return 1;
    }

    // loop through all the results and make a socket
    for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
        if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype,
                             p->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
            perror("talker: socket");
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }

    if (p == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "talker: failed to bind socket\n");
        return 2;
    }

    fp = fopen("wilde-tiobe.txt", "rb");
    printf("Size of packet : %d", sizeof send);

    while (1) {
        memset((void *) &send, '\0', sizeof send);

        send.seq = seq;
        send.round = round;
        memset(send.data, '\0', DATA);
        bytes_read = read(fileno(fp), send.data, DATA );
        send.length = bytes_read;
        if (bytes_read < DATA) {
            send.last = 1;
            printf("****last byte***\n");
        }
        strcpy(send.crc, "yet to calcula\0");
        totalBytes+= bytes_read;

        //if(bytes_read == 0) break;

        if ((numbytes = sendto(sockfd, &send, sizeof send, 0,
                               p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen)) == -1) {
            perror("talker: sendto");
            exit(1);
        }
        usleep(60000);
        if (send.last) break;
    }

    fclose(fp);
    printf("Total bytes transferred : %lu\n", totalBytes);

    freeaddrinfo(servinfo);

    close(sockfd);

    return 0;
}
```

and here is the code for my receiver :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#define MYPORT "4950"   // the port users will be connecting to

#define MAXBUFLEN 196
#define DATA 170

typedef struct packet_ {
    unsigned short int seq;
    unsigned short int round;
    unsigned short int last;
    unsigned short int length;
    unsigned char data[DATA];
    unsigned char crc[17];
} packet;

// get sockaddr, IPv4 or IPv6:
void *get_in_addr(struct sockaddr *sa)
{
    if (sa->sa_family == AF_INET) {
        return &(((struct sockaddr_in*)sa)->sin_addr);
    }

    return &(((struct sockaddr_in6*)sa)->sin6_addr);
}

int main(void)
{
    int sockfd;
    struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
    int rv;
    FILE *fp;
    int numbytes;
    struct sockaddr_storage their_addr;
    char buf[MAXBUFLEN];
    socklen_t addr_len;
    char s[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
    packet * recv, recv_packet;
    fp = fopen("wtf.bmp", "wb");

    printf("size of packet :%d", sizeof(packet));
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);

    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC; // set to AF_INET to force IPv4
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE; // use my IP

    if ((rv = getaddrinfo(NULL, MYPORT, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
        return 1;
    }

    // loop through all the results and bind to the first we can
    for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
        if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype,
                             p->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
            perror("listener: socket");
            continue;
        }

        if (bind(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
            close(sockfd);
            perror("listener: bind");
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }

    if (p == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "listener: failed to bind socket\n");
        return 2;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(servinfo);

    addr_len = sizeof their_addr;

    while(1) {
        printf("listener: waiting to recvfrom...\n");
        if ((numbytes = recvfrom(sockfd, buf, MAXBUFLEN , 0,
                                 (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr,
                                  &addr_len)) == -1) {
            perror("recvfrom");
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("listener: got packet from %s\n",
                inet_ntop(their_addr.ss_family,
                        get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)&their_addr),
                        s, sizeof s));
        printf("listener: packet is %d bytes long\n", numbytes);
        //printf("listener: packet contains \"%s\"\n", buf);
        recv = (packet *) buf;
        if (!recv_packet.data) {
            printf("NO memory\n");
            break;
        }
        memset(&recv_packet, 0, sizeof recv_packet);
        recv_packet.seq  = recv->seq;
        recv_packet.round = recv->round;
        recv_packet.last = recv->last;
        recv_packet.length = recv->length;
        memset(recv_packet.data, '\0', DATA);
        strncpy(recv_packet.data, recv->data, recv_packet.length);
        strncpy(recv_packet.crc, recv->crc, 17);
        //printf(" len: %hu  and data: %s \n", recv_packet.length, recv_packet.data);
        write(fileno(fp), recv_packet.data, recv_packet.length);
        if (recv_packet.last) {
            printf("Last packet\n");
            break;
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);
    close(sockfd);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Probably not why you're having problems, but why on earth are you jumping through hoops to use `write` when you are using a `FILE *`, when you could be using `fwrite`? It would help if you explained what sort of differences you see in your binary file (using "od" or similar tool should help examine the binary file.

Comment: May be a silly question, but when you say that the diff's don't match, are you using a tool that can diff binary files?

Comment: @AnishRam : check this out : http://www.cryst.bbk.ac.uk/CCSG/unix/unix_for_beginners/cmp.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already had a similar problem with socket because I was sending a buffer of "unsigned char[]", and receiving into a buffer of "char[]", I dont think is your problem because you do not do any manipulation within the signed array, but any way is good to avoid those casts, and it worth the shot.

use

```
unsigned char buf[MAXBUFLEN];
```

instead of

```
char buf[MAXBUFLEN];
```

Also clear your buffer before receiving the packet, and check the value of "numbytes" before continuing the process.
Example:

```
    printf("listener: waiting to recvfrom...\n");
    memset(buff, 0, sizeof(buff));
    numbytes=0;
    while ( (numbytes += recvfrom(sockfd, &buf[numbytes], MAXBUFLEN - numbytes , 0,
                                 (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr,
                              &addr_len)) < sizeof(packet))
        printf("Oops, the package is not full, lets read it again.");
    }
```

Or try to pass the MSG_WAITALL flag when using recvfrom to read entire blocks of memory, but I still prefer to check the amount of data read every time.

Comment: yeah i guess thats the problem let me check out. my bad

Comment: it works but I made the following change in recvfrom instead of receiving in buf I receive directly in the packet structure. but i will still try with unsigned char. thanks for your suggestion.